# How to markup Information about Phonics using schema.org

Tags: html, schema.org

I am practising marking up a page of information. The information is just the phonetic sounds we use in primary school and their corresponding Graphemes (how the sounds are written).

I want to use [Structured Data](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data) so that search engines have a better grasp of what the information is about but I do not know what tags to use.

I just have a table with Phoneme (the sound) written /a/ and Grapheme a. Some sounds have alternative Graphemes. This is the JSON for /s/:

```
    {
"phoneme": "s",
"grapheme": {
  "main": "s",
  "alt1": "ss",
  "alt2": "c",
  "alt3": "sc",
  "alt4": "ps",
  "alt5": "st",
  "alt6": "ce",
  "alt7": "se"
},
```

Could you suggest how to mark this info up in my HTML?